Spring Boot Azure B2C Swagger authentication
I'm experiencing problems with authenticating via swagger ui that uses azure b2c.
The error seems to be indicating that some code_challenge is missing, though this is not something that i was able to find/add manually to my config. Neither in azure config nor in swagger.

Here's my config:
Swagger config
@Bean
    public OpenAPI openApi() {
        return new OpenAPI()
            .info(new Info()
                .title("API")
                .version("1.0.0"))
            .addServersItem(new Server().url("http://localhost:8080"))
            .components(new Components()
                .addSecuritySchemes("oauth2", new SecurityScheme()
                        .type(OAUTH2)
                        .description("Sign in with Azure AD B2C OAuth2")
                        .flows(new OAuthFlows()
                            .authorizationCode(new OAuthFlow()
                                .authorizationUrl("https://costcoapp.b2clogin.com/costcoapp.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_signupsignin1/oauth2/v2.0/authorize")
                                .tokenUrl("https://costcoapp.b2clogin.com/costcoapp.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_signupsignin1/oauth2/v2.0/token")
                                .scopes(new Scopes()
                                    .addString("https://costcoapp.onmicrosoft.com/f342g5-5a6b-4341-a4fc-3674gr52779/read", "Read access to demo API")
                                    
                                )
                            )
                        )
                )
                .addSecuritySchemes("bearerToken",
                    new SecurityScheme()
                        .type(HTTP)
                        .description("Use Access Token obtained from Azure AD B2C OAuth2")
                        .scheme("bearer")
                        .bearerFormat("JWT")
                )
            );
    }

Security config
    @Configuration
@EnableMethodSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    private final AadB2cOidcLoginConfigurer configurer;

    private final JwtClaimResolver jwtClaimResolver;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests(config -> config
                .requestMatchers("/swagger-ui/**", "/v3/api-docs/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated())
            .oauth2ResourceServer(config -> config
                .jwt()
                .jwtAuthenticationConverter(jwtAuthenticationConverter()))
            .formLogin(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
            .logout(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
            .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
            .httpBasic(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable);
        http.sessionManagement($ -> $.sessionCreationPolicy(STATELESS));
        http.apply(configurer);
        return http.build();
    }

    private JwtAuthenticationConverter jwtAuthenticationConverter() {
        JwtAuthenticationConverter jwtAuthenticationConverter = new JwtAuthenticationConverter();
        jwtAuthenticationConverter.setJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter(jwt -> jwtClaimResolver.getUserGroups(jwt)
            .stream()
            .map(this::mapToGrantedAuthority)
            .toList());
        return jwtAuthenticationConverter;
    }

    private GrantedAuthority mapToGrantedAuthority(String userGroup) {
        return new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_" + userGroup);
    }

}

application.yaml config
   spring:
  cloud:
    azure:
      active-directory:
        b2c:
          enabled: true
          profile:
            tenant-id: <my-tenant-id>
          credential:
            client-id: <my-client-id>
            client-secret: <my-secret>
          base-uri: https://costcoapp.b2clogin.com/costcoapp.onmicrosoft.com
          user-flows:
            sign-up-or-sign-in: B2C_1_signupsignin1

springdoc:
  api-docs:
    enabled: true
  swagger-ui:
    oauth:
      client-id: <my-client-id>
      client-secret: <my-secret>
    oauth2-redirect-url: http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/oauth2-redirect.html

Update:
Extra, i've tried another approach following suggestion from Azure docs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/authorization-code-flow), i've added code challenge via following code amendments though that didn't help much, although threw another error this time:
AADB2C90184: The supplied code_challenge_method is not supported. Supported values are plain or S256.
  @SneakyThrows
        private String generateChallenge() {
            SecureRandom secureRandom = new SecureRandom();
            int cvLength = secureRandom.nextInt(85) + 43;
            String chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789-._~";
            StringBuilder codeVerifier = new StringBuilder(cvLength);
            for (int i = 0; i < cvLength; i++) {
                codeVerifier.append(chars.charAt(secureRandom.nextInt(chars.length())));
            }
    
            MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
            byte[] encodedHash = digest.digest(codeVerifier.toString().getBytes(java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    
            return Base64.getUrlEncoder().withoutPadding().encodeToString(encodedHash);
        }
    
        @SneakyThrows
        private URL buildAuthUrl() {
            String challenge = generateChallenge();
            String baseUrl = "https://costcoapp.b2clogin.com/costcoapp.onmicrosoft.com/b2c_1_signupsignin1/oauth2/v2.0/authorize";
    
            UriComponentsBuilder uriBuilder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(baseUrl)
                .queryParam("client_id", "f342g5-5a6b-4341-a4fc-3674gr52779")
                .queryParam("response_type", "code")
                .queryParam("redirect_uri", "http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/oauth2-redirect.html")
                .queryParam("response_mode", "query")
                .queryParam("scope", "openid")
                .queryParam("code_challenge", challenge)
                .queryParam("code_challenge_method", "plain");
    
            return  uriBuilder.build().toUri().toURL();
        }


That's because you are using a PKCE flow that requires a code_challenge.

Hi, thanks for info, but where do you see pkce? I can't find any mention of it in my code

I did set pkce explicitly false  use-pkce-with-authorization-code-grant: false though problem still persists
